# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null but code is working

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a soundboard website which has a number of small audio clips and the below Javascript to play, pause and reset them when they are finished playing. The page works exactly as expected but I get a

> *index.html:90 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null*

error in my Javascript console and I have no idea why.

```
cliplist = ['audio1','audio2','audio3','audio4','audio5','audio6','audio7','audio8'];
playerlist = ['player1','player2','player3','player4','player5','player6','player7','player8'];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() 
{
    for(let i=0;i<cliplist.length;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(playerlist[i]).addEventListener("click", function()
        {
            playClip(cliplist[i]);
        })

        document.getElementById(playerlist[i]).addEventListener("click", function()
        {
            playClip(cliplist[i],playerlist[i]);
        })

                document.getElementById(cliplist[i]).addEventListener("ended", function()
        {
            reset(playerlist[i]);
        })
    }
});

function playClip(theclip,theplayer)
{
    playerElement = document.getElementById(theplayer);
    clipElement = document.getElementById(theclip)

    if(playerElement.getAttribute("src") == 'playbutton.png')
    {
        playerElement.setAttribute("src","pausebutton.png");
        clipElement.play();
    }
    else
    {
        playerElement.setAttribute("src","playbutton.png");
        clipElement.pause();        
    }

}

function reset(theplayer)
{
    document.getElementById(theplayer).src = 'playbutton.png';  
}
```

Comment: basically it tells you it cannot find one of the elements with `document.getElementById(theplayer);` check all the elements to see if they are there

`['player1','player2','player3','player4','player5','player6','player7','player8']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a call to `playClip` that looks like this:

```
playClip(cliplist[i]);
```

It only passes one argument. But, `playClip()` expects a second argument and that is what is used with `.getElementById()`, which gets a DOM element that `.getAttribute()` is called on. When you don't pass the argument, you don't get a DOM element and you get the error.

So, make sure that you pass it the two arguments it's looking for, like in the other spot where you wrote:

```
playClip(cliplist[i],playerlist[i]);
```

Lastly, the reason it still works is because you are adding two `click` event hanlders to `document.getElementById(playerlist[i])`. The first one throws the error and the second one works.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I must have looked at that code for about half an hour and failed to see I had a duplicate event listener. Thank you!